# IIS 7.0 Session expiring ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, iis, session-timeout

This is the syntax am using in `web.config`.

But my session get expire within 10 to 15 minutes not staying upto 2 hrs.

```
<sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" cookieName="ASP.NET_SessionId180" 
mode="InProc" timeout="120" />
```

Comment: Is the date and time on the server correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "worker" is most likely the one who causes your problem. If it recycle it will reset the session if its idle long enough.

Check your IIS AppPool setting and increase the idle timeout setting.

Answer (score 2):

One possible cause is that the application domain gets recycled by IIS. And since you are using InProc session state the whole memory of the AppDomain gets wiped out. IIS could recycle the AppDomain under different circumstances: certain period of inactivity or CPU/memory threshold limits are reached.

You can read more about this in the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx).

Comment: Which is 10 or 20 minutes tmieout by default.

Answer (score 0):

As you use the InProc session state, it's possible that the pool is recycled due to some actions: modifying web.config, copying files to the bin folder,...
Check also the recycling parameters of the pool.
You can try to use the StateServer option for your session. To do this, you need to start the ASP.NET state service and check that your objects are marked as serializable.