# IIS Session Expire after few minutes even if configured to last hours

Tags: session, iis, timeout

I have a problem very similar to this one :
[IIS 7.0 Session expiring ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487267/iis-7-0-session-expiring-asp-net)

After 20 minutes session expire and the customer have to login again into the site i have developed (annoying).
I have configured IIS limit of 4 hours before session expired, then i checked the process Ilde timeout and set it also to 4 hours with periodic recycle every 29h.
No configuration in web.config to enforce the session timeout, no Session.Abandon() in code behind or anithng that should impact the session (as far as i know).
I have checked error log and found no crash that may cause an app recylce and so a session expiration (also the expiration happens every 20 min very regularly, i tend to exclude a random exception)

Still have session expired after 20 minutes and have no idea of what originate that bheaviour.

Here few screenshot of the system setup and configuration :
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your application asp.net? If so, you could set the session time out in IIS manager->site node->session state.

[image]

Besides, asp.net application also have an element like:

`<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20"/>` to set the session time out in web.config.

Load event Session.Timeout = 20 can also set the session time out.

`<sessionState cookieless="false" timeout="480" />` can also set the time out.

Comment: Thanks, i had removed the parameter from web.config but somewhat it remain (and whas applied) in the GUI. I was sure the to "values" are keep in sync (basically the GUI just display what placed in web config).
Anyway that worked, thanks again